# undefined reference to functions in gzip

Tags: gzip, mbedtls, hiawatha

When I was trying to build the Hiawatha webserver, I got the following error:

[  1%] Linking C executable cgi-wrapper
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cgi-wrapper.dir/src/libfs.c.o: in function `gzip_file': /home/yliang19/Downloads/hiawatha-11.3/src/libfs.c:403: undefined reference to` gzopen64'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/yliang19/Downloads/hiawatha-11.3/src/libfs.c:424: undefined reference to `gzclose' /usr/bin/ld: /home/yliang19/Downloads/hiawatha-11.3/src/libfs.c:417: undefined reference to` gzwrite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/yliang19/Downloads/hiawatha-11.3/src/libfs.c:424: undefined reference to `gzclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But gzip has been installed by default and is already the newest version. The makefile is generated by cmake. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Tried to install gzip and no change was made.

gzip is already the newest version (1.10-4ubuntu4.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.

The error stays the same when running "make install".

Comment: It's looking for zlib, not gzip. `sudo apt install zlib`

Comment: Zlib has been installed.
zlib1g/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed]
  compression library - runtime

zlib1g-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2 amd64 [installed]
  compression library - development

Comment: Alright... Retried and succeeded...